# UICollectionView incorrect edge insets in landscape mode

Tags: ios, ios5

When I launch my view controller in landscape, cells are in wrong places (incorrect placement from left and right side), but after I rotate everything works fine both in portrait and landscape.
What can be done about that? I tried invalidating layout, calling rotation methods to no avail.

Here is my code:

Setting up flow layout:

```
self.flowLayout = [[PSTCollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
self.flowLayout.scrollDirection = PSTCollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
self.flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = VERTICAL_ITEM_SPACING;
self.flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = HORIZONTAL_ITEM_SPACING;
```

Method for insets:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(PSTCollectionView *)collectionView
                        layout:(PSTCollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
        insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

    self.currentOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    self.insets = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.currentOrientation) ? UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 72, 24, 72) : UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 35, 24, 35);

    //[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];

    return self.insets;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass PSTCollectionViewFlowLayout

```
@interface FlowLayout : PSTCollectionViewFlowLayout
```

set all property inside init of FlowLayout

```
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.scrollDirection = PSTCollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = VERTICAL_ITEM_SPACING;
        self.minimumLineSpacing = HORIZONTAL_ITEM_SPACING;

        self.currentOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
        self.sectionInset = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.currentOrientation) ? UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 72, 24, 72) : UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 35, 24, 35);

    }

    return self;
}
```

//Then init your Flowlayout

```
self.flowLayout = [[FlowLayout alloc] init];
```

//Reset flowlayout anytime device rotate

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = [[FlowLayout alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: This is the only approach that works. The section insets are not updated when you invalidate the layout, whether you use the `sectionInset` property or the `collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:` delegate method. I filed a [bug report](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5255754231578624) with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an error, I was measuring the positions of cells by the separate top view, and it was position of that that was wrong. Cells were working fine.